# create a function that apply activation function on a list of numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a method that takes as input a list or a single number x and output the result of applying the RELU function on it. For example, 
Given that an array `a=[-1,2,3,-0.4,22,12,-0.6,22,3]`, I want to apply the RELU function on the array to get `[0,2,3,0,22,12,0,22.3]`. Here is what I tried: `[if x>=0 then x else 0 for x in a]`. But it didn't work. But I was able to get a list of Boolean specifying which entries are positive and which entries are negative as follow: `[float(x>=0) : x in a]`

Comment: there was an invalid syntax error at the if statement

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this by creating your own function:

```
import numpy as np
def relu(a):
    return np.maximum(0, a)

a=[-1,2,3,-0.4,22,12,-0.6,22,3]
return_a = relu(a)
print(return_a)
```

Result into

```
[ 0.  2.  3.  0. 22. 12.  0. 22.  3.]
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your commands are valid python, but you were close with the first one. It is called list comprehension and the syntax is like that

```
[x if x>0 else 0 for x in a]
```

Which gives

```
[0, 2, 3, 0, 22, 12, 0, 22, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

`[if x>=0 then x else 0 for x in a]` is not valid Python syntax. Use

```
[x if x > 0 else 0 for x in a]
```

Neither is `[float(x>=0) : x in a]`. `:` is in Java loops, in Python it's

```
[float(x >= 0) for x in a]
```